# Do I need a Google Play Developer Account for Google Analytics in my Android app?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-developers-console

I'm working on an app and I want to add Google Analytics to it, but I think I have a problem, The Google Play Developer Account that I use is a different Google account then the account where all the Google Analytics are tracked.

So I was wondering if the Developer Account and the Analytics account should be on the same Google account or if it could with separate accounts. If it would work I would also want to know if there are any disadvantages with doing it this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any google account for Google Analytics . 
You just need to generate the google-services.json file fron the Google Api Console with the account you want view Analytic Reports.
i.e. You don't need a Google Play Developer Account for accessing Google Api Console.

You can follow this link for setting up Google Analytics : - 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/